# Adding and Subtracting Shapes

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, caanimation

If I need to add or subtract two shapes together and animate it as a whole entity, what is the easiest way to do it? For example if I subtract a smaller circle from a bigger circle, i get a donut.

If I then need to animate this entity and also animate many of this type of entities (donuts or whatever) will it be heavy on an iPad?

I need a direction to look into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is marked with the keyword "Core-Graphics," so I assume that's what you want to use. To add shapes, you simply draw the 2 or more shapes you want together. I recommend following a pattern of saving the graphics state, drawing your connected shapes, and the restore the graphics state for drawing the next set of shapes. Like this:

```
// Save the state
CGContextSaveGState (ctx);
// Do your drawing
CGContextBeginPath (ctx);
CGContextAddRect (ctx, rect);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect (ctx, ellipseRect); // Or whatever
CGContextClosePath (ctx);
CGContextFillPath (ctx);
// Restore the state
CGContextRestoreGState (ctx);
```

To subtract shapes, you can use a clipping path:

```
// This is the path you want to draw within
CGContextBeginPath (ctx);
CGContextAddRect (ctx);
CGContextClosePath (ctx);
CGContextClip (ctx);
// Now draw the shape you want constrained within the above path
CGContextBeginPath (ctx);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect (ctx, ellipseRect);
CGContextClosePath (ctx);
CGContextFillPath (ctx); // This will fill everything in the path that is also within the clipping path, and nothing that is outside of the clipping path
```

See also `CGContextEOClip()` for other ways to clip shapes.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This is method is what I know and I wonder if there are better and more efficient methods out there or this method will be good enough for my needs.